# NGINX hangs on closed websocket upstream connections

Tags: nginx

I am utilizing the `upstream` block to load balance two `nodejs` instances:

```
upstream Balancer {
   least_conn; 
   server 127.0.0.1:9300; 
   server 127.0.0.1:9301; 
}
```

Location Directive:

```
    location = /Balancer {
                    proxy_pass http://Balancer;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        }
```

All works fine. But, if the `9301` instance goes down and when a new player connects to the `Balancer` directive, `nginx` hangs and doesn't connect to `9300` (which is the only one alive). It seems like it's still trying to connect to `9301`... which is dead.

I have tried the `weight` option, like so:

```
upstream Balancer {
   least_conn; 
   server 127.0.0.1:9300 weight=1; 
   server 127.0.0.1:9301 weight=2; 
}
```

Is this maybe a `nginx` issue or is my configuration wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am missing the `proxy_connect_timeout 1s;` setting.

```
        location = /Balancer {
                proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
                proxy_pass http://Balancer;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        }
```

All works now. Looks like `nginx` now waits for around `1s` to test if theres a valid connection, if not, it moves on to the next server. This setting must be enabled or the connection will hang. (That might be intended, or a bug, not sure)